# What kind of data does Script Lab collect (if any)?

Tags: office-js

On the [Script Lab add-in page](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/wa104380862), we can read that:

> When this add-in is used, it can send data over the Internet.

What kind of data is being sent over? More specifically, when using Script Lab to create and run Excel JS add-ins, is the spreadsheet data sent over the internet? Or is that data strictly processed locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that *every* add-in in the Store will have that bullet point of being able to send data over the internet.  An add-in is just a website (plus a reference to Office.js to call APIs on the document, plus a manifest file for registering the functionality with Office).  Which means that an add-in, by definition, transfers data over the internet, even just in terms of loading the actual web content!  And of course, it also *can* (and in some cases does) send data over the internet as well -- e.g., in the case of Script Lab, publishing a script to a GitHub Gist.

That being said:  the scripts you run are run directly on the workbook that you have open, which means that in the case of Office for Desktop/Mac, all the data remains local (unless you have the file syncing to OneDrive or Dropbox or whatnot, but that's irrelevant from Script Lab's perspective).  If you are running Office Online, then of course your data already *is* in the Cloud -- but still, it remains within Office Online's services, not with Script Lab.

Script Lab can publish your scripts to the internet, but only if you log in with GitHub and explicitly ask to have your script published as either a public or secret Gist.

Beyond that, some data is collected by the underlying Office platform (e.g., the fact that you launched the add-in, what browser you were using, etc.), but it's all anonymized and contains no personally identifiable information.  We don't store any of your scripts or any other user-generated contents.

Hope this helps!